# My code returns the error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

i created a python flask webapp that webscrapes using selenium chromedriver and then deployed it on heroku. the problem im facing is that this line driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options) makes the rest of my code unreachable on VsCode and on top of that it returns that error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType when im running it. please help

Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time


class Letsgo:
    def scrape(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
        chrome_options.headless = True
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)

        driver.get("https://letsgo-bot.herokuapp.com/login?next=%2Fdashboard")
        time.sleep(2)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        original_window = driver.current_window_handle
        assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1
```

i tried upgrading the python version from 3.8 to 3.11 then back down to 3.10 then 3.9 and that didnt help. i also put this code on a seperate class and created a function and returned this 'driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)' then imported the class and called the function, this made the rest of my code reachable however i got the error module not found for the class i created.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time

class WebChrome:
    def chrome_func():
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
        chrome_options.headless = True 
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        return chrome_options
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_func())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in _call_
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\lamla hub\damp-beach-65563\user.py", line 12, in wrap
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\lamla hub\damp-beach-65563\run.py", line 218, in apply_results
    instance.wsu_apply()
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\lamla hub\damp-beach-65563\uni\wsu.py", line 18, in wsu_apply
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in _init_
    super()._init_(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in _init_
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in _init_
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1360, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\subprocess.py", line 565, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\os.py", line 822, in fsdecode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: **Always post the full error message including the stack trace** as formatted text. Why would you not post that?

Comment: But it *sounds* like `os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH")` is returning `None`.

Comment: yes, os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH") is returning None

Comment: Why do you *expect* it to be anything else?

Comment: Have you used appropriate buildpacks to install a Chromedriver and browser on Heroku?

Comment: yes i have used the appropriate buildpacks

Comment: i have added both these buidpacks                               
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome                                                   https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

Comment: and i also added config vars and their values as well

Comment: i have upgraded the selenium version, which solved the issue of the rest of the code being unreachable on Vscode. i ran the code again now im getting this error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home